# Open ready-made Lua files

Tags: eclipse-plugin, lua, luabind

I am new to the Lua language. . .  I have some ready made .lua source files. Now I want to edit it and also want to modify it. First, I want to open and see it.

I have searched on net, and found that it may be opened in Notepad, but when I open it in Notepad it shows some garbage value. . . .

Can anybody help me to open it and read it?

Thanks in advance. . .

Comment: *Lua*, not *LUA*. See http://www.lua.org/about.html#name

Answer (score 3):

If the garbage appears at the beginning of the file, it's probably a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) . In this case it's an editor problem, not a Lua problem. Otherwise, perhaps you have a precompiled Lua script? In this case, try `luac -l`  on it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Lua strings can actually contain binary chunks, or chunks in an encoding not recognized by your editor. That may be what you're seeing. (for example: http://codepad.org/jF4q4JHZ)

Or you got passed a compiled lua file which has been given a .lua extension, as lhf suggested.

Answer (score 0):

lua files are plain text, so if you're seeing garbage, it's not a lua file.

Comment: I mean there are some coading in file and the file extention is .lua but wen i open it in to the Notepad it cant shows whole text. Some texts are shown and some are of garbage type text. . .  then what should i do to read it ?

Comment: try a real programming editor such as PsPad on Windows, in addition to being a full featured editor you get syntax highlighting!